# Php connecting but failing to select a database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am having trouble getting php to connect to my mysql database on a shared hosting. This worked when it was on my MAMP local server.

I get the following error:

Error: No database selected Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /hermes/bosnaweb03b/b2270/ipg.theburguersaredownco/cheval/main.php on line 34

My db_connect php file:

```
 <?php
$connect = mysqli_connect('theburguersaredownco.ipagemysql.com', 'user', 'password');
if (!$connect) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully';
mysqli_select_db('db_cheval'); 
?>
```

I get the message: "Connected successfully", so I am assuming the connection to the database is established and therefore there are no issues with the mysql_connect function or any of its arguments (i.e. the user and password are correct etc...).

my main.php file:

```
<?php
  include 'db_connect.php';
  include 'header.php';

  error_reporting( E_ALL );
  ini_set( "display_errors", 1 );
  ?>

<a id="roundLogo" href="index.php" class="not-active"></a><div>

</div></a>

<div id="subheader" class="notVisible">

  <nav id="menu2">
    <ul>
  <?php
      $query = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM categories");

      if (!$query) {
          printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($connect));
          // exit();
      }

      while ($q = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {

        if($q['id']<4){ ?>

etc...
```

Line 34 is this one:

```
  while ($q = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
```

It is the first time I do this and I am new to php and mysql so I don't have much experience. Can someone help me find the problem here. How can I debug this?

Thank you

Comment: Save the result of `mysqli_select_db(...);` in a variable and check/output it with `var_dump()`. What is the result you get? What is the error message you get when you use `mysqli_error()`? Please edit your question with these new informations.

Answer (score 1):

You should use **localhost** for host parameter even if you running on hosting or local webserver but your problem is missing parameter in **[mysqli_select_db](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_select_db.asp)** that why "**No database selected**" return

```
$connect=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }    
mysqli_select_db($connect,"db_cheval");
```